# How to customise the view for post list in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

Change the view of default post list for custom post type in wp-admin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like Admin Columns:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/